# How to best read ByteBuffer twice?

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I'm getting a `DataBuffer` as input argument, which is a wrapper for `ByteBuffer`. Now I want to log the full content of the buffer. Further, I have to pass that buffer to an external library.

Thus, as I cannot read the `ByteBuffer` twice, I either have to reset the buffer, or recreate it from `String`.

Question: which of the following approaches should be preferred (or is there even another better one)?

```
//Input:
DataBuffer dataBuffer;

//common logging:
ByteBuffer bb = dataBuffer.asByteBuffer();
String bufferContent = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(bb).toString();
LOGGER.info(bufferContent);

//then either reset the buffer:
bb.rewind();
externalService.call(dataBuffer);

//or convert the string content back to buffer:
externalService.call(new DefaultDataBufferFactory().wrap(bufferContent.getBytes()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Duplicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#duplicate--) the buffer to preserve the original's position, limit, and mark values.

```
String bufferContent = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(bb.duplicate()).toString();
```

Comment: What if I wanna read it from the beginning, independently of the current position?

Comment: You may reset the position to zero with: `dataBuffer.readPosition(0)`